# Title() python string that contains numbers

Tags: python

I have a string like this: 
    "CURICO 394 DEPTO 1013"

and I want this output

"Curico 394 Depto 1013"

How could I accomplish that in Python 2.7?

Comment: `"CURICO 394 DEPTO 1013".title()`? It works, but judging by your title, you’ve tried that, so what happened?

Comment: Check out this `.capwords` function, here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-functions

Comment: This should do it: https://launchpad.net/titlecase.py/trunk/0.2

Comment: ares1986 - please answer @minitech's question.  why does `.title()` not work for you?

Comment: Actually, minitech answers is the correct. I tried it but the particular example had some accent in between and for that reason it wasn't working. For the example that I put there, the correct answer is to simple use .title(). Thanks to everyone!